# select max(id) de cada* registro

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: elect]

opa pessoal, tenho um query com esses dados da imagem, queria dar um select apenas no max(id) de cada numeroExterno para guardar em outra tabela@

Comment: *"queria dar um select apenas no max(id) de cada numeroExterno"* isso não faz sentido "de cada numeroExterno", se é max vai ser de todos, senão não seria um max. quanto a inserir em outra tabela só fazer insert com select ou select into

Comment: vou reformular minha pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar o max(id) para cada numeroExterno, faça um select com group by

Exemplo:

```
select
    max(ID),
    NUMEROEXTERNO
from
    BA_COBAN.DETALHELOJAARQCADASTRAL
where
    NUMEROEXTERNOMATRIZ = '50494'
```

Agora utilize esse select para fazer join no select que você já tem para fazer o insert na tabela, assim vai filtrar apenas o max de cada numero externo.

Exemplo:

```
select
    *
from
    (select
         max(ID),
         NUMEROEXTERNO
     from
         BA_COBAN.DETALHELOJAARQCADASTRAL
     where
         NUMEROEXTERNOMATRIZ = '50494') X
inner join BA_COBAN.DETALHELOJAARQCADASTRAL DE on DE.ID = X.ID
```

Comment: @Diego Garcia Se a resposta lhe foi útil, se puder marque-a como aceita `√`, assim quando outros usuários visualizarem sua questão verão que já tem uma resposta correta e aceita por você.